# Loop through the div tag containing paragraph tags

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape information from an automobile blog but i can't loop through the div tag containing the paragraph tags that contain the info.

```
driver.get("https://www.autocar.co.uk/car-news")
driver.maximize_window()

for i in range(3):
    i+=1
    info = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="page"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[{i}]/div')))

heading = info.find_element_by_tag_name('h2')
clickable = heading.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", clickable)
# the code starts to fail around here
try:
    body_info =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'field-item even')))
        
    main_text = []
    for j in range(3):
        j+=1
        text = body_info.find_element_by_tag_name('p')
        main_text.append(text)
        for t in main_text:
            t_info = t.text
    print(f'{heading.text}\n{t_info}')
except:
    print("couldn't find tag")

driver.back()
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with your code, `(By.CLASS_NAME, 'field-item even')`.

`Selenium` does not have support for `multiple classes` or `classes` with space.

Simply `replace` space with `.` and that would be the `CSS_SELECTOR`

Try something like this:

```
try:
    body_info =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.field-item.even')))
```

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple classes, you must use the class selector. You can't select multiple classes through a space, like in CSS. You need to select multiple classes using the class selector. So you must put a dot before all of the classes and not give any space between them

Comment: Right, but can you explain?

Comment: see, you can't select multiple classes through a space, like in css. You need to select class using the class selector. So you must put a dot before of all of the classes and not give any space between them

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer and add this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It must be `'.field-item even'` and not `'field-item even'` if you are using `By.CSS_SELECTOR` for `presence_of_element_located()`.

So Replace,

```
body_info =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'field-item even')))
```

with,

```
body_info =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'field-item even')))
```

Official docs. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#locate-elements-by